# Partial derivative of square formula

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to know the partial derivative w.r.t '$b$' of the following equation:

$$1/2(a-b)^2$$

I have tried solving it down but my overall answer computed due to this derivative is incorrect.

Please help.

Comment: You should probably clarify whether the function in your post is $\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2$ or $\frac{1}{2(a-b)^2}$. With priority of operators, the way you wrote it means $\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2$ but I am not sure that this is what you meant

Comment: The answer you have given is what I was expecting. That's right. I am referring to the former equation in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the classical formula for the derivative of a composition of two functions $(f \circ g)(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$ you get

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( \frac{1}{2} (a-b)^2 \right)
= (a-b) \times (-1) = b - a
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would also want to know what is the derivative of summation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: For eg. What is the partial derivative of summation(k=1 to N) of W(k)?

Comment: Differentiation and partial derivative are linear operations, so for instance the partial derivative of $\sum_{k=1}^N f_k(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x} (x,y)$. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: That's ok. But then when we calculates the answer where does that sigma (summation) goes? Does it stays till the end in the answer as well? Or is there any way in derivate to disappear sigma(summation)?

Comment: I want the derivative of summation (k=1 to N) of W(k) w.r.t W(k)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand what you mean. Is $W(k)$ a variable ? You should be as precise as possible

Comment: Yes W(k) is a variable whose partial derivative is to be calculated w.r.t W(k) with summation.

Comment: Please refer to my another question I just posted minutes ago on partial derivative of summation. You may get some clearer idea over there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to calculate $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{1}{2(a-b)^2} $$.

As Dodo say, you have to use the chain rule. Here $f(x)=\frac{1}{2x^2}$ and $g(x)=a-b$ , so $f \circ g (x) = \frac{1}{2(a-b)^2}$

The chain rule say then:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{1}{2(a-b)^2} = \frac{-1}{4(a-b)^3} (-1) = \frac{1}{4(a-b)^3} $$.